# Return a message of exactly what was updated when data is auto updated in Excel table

Tags: vba, excel

I want a message box to show when the value in cell D7 is greater than 0. The message box should ask if the check is a low risk item. If `No`, enter `0` in cell D9 and go to D11. If `Yes`, a textbox should show to enter a number in. This number will be copied to cell D9.

It sounds so simple, and I can't figure it out.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'   Code goes in the Worksheet specific module
Dim rng As Range
Dim Response As Long
Dim Risk As Long
    '   Set Target Range, i.e. Range("A1, B2, C3"), or Range("A1:B3")
    Set rng = Target.Parent.Range("D7")
         '   Only look at single cell changes
        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        '   Only look at that range
        If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        '   Action if Condition(s) are met (do your thing here...)
        If Target.Value > 0 Then
            Response = MsgBox("Is the check a low risk item?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Item Risk Assessment")
            Select Case Response
                Case 6 '    Yes
                    Risk = Application.InputBox("Enter a new value", "Value required", Type:=1)
                    Range("D9").Value = Risk
                Case 7  '   No
                  Range("D9").Value = 0
                    Range("D11").Select
            End Select
        End If
End Sub
```

This works only when the cell is modified manually but I'm trying to set this up so it gives the message when the cell is not updated manually but automatically as it has a formula for calculated data.

Comment: Is the formula that drives the cell in the same sheet? If so, you can reconfigure your code to check the value of D7 after every input and perhaps put in checks to ensure it only checks on specific cell entries so that if someone randomly enters data in cells off to the side and D7=0 it doesn't trigger it inadvertently?

Comment: Hey Scott, Yes the formula is in the same sheet. Maybe i'm not understanding you fully can you re-iterate?

Comment: Sam - I was referring to something like Dick put in the first part of his answer below. If you know the precedents of the formula, you can limit the `Worksheet_Change` event to perform a check on only those cells.

Comment: Ah copy that, sorry for misunderstanding. Dick had provided handy information and truly appreciate your response Scott.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know all the direct and indirect precedents to D7, you can use the Change event on those cells. So if D7 contained `=SUM(D5:D6)` and D5 and D6 were input cells, then you could

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D5:D6")) Is Nothing Then
    If Me.Range("D7").Value = 0 Then
```

If there are a lot of precedents, this gets a little unwieldy.

Or you could use the Worksheet_Calculate event and continually check the value of D7. This is usually a bad idea. For one, it will run all the time and might degrade the performance of you worksheet. Second, if a message box popped up every time the worksheet calculated, I'd probably quit my job. If you do go the Calculate event route, the procedure might look like

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    '   Code goes in the Worksheet specific module

    Dim lResponse As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Me.Range("D7").Value > 0 Then
        lResponse = MsgBox("Is the check a low risk item?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Item Risk Assessment")
        If lResponse = vbYes Then
            Me.Range("D9").Value = Application.InputBox("Enter a new value", "Value required", Type:=1)
        Else
            Me.Range("D9").Value = 0
            Me.Range("D11").Select
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Finally, you might consider just putting the prompt directly on the spreadsheet. Put this text in C9:

```
Enter a new value for low risk, enter 0 for high risk:
```

and make the text color and interior color the same so it's hidden. Then add conditional formatting to make it visible when D7 = 0. You'll need one final check, like Before_Save, to make sure the user entered a number. Or you could conditional format D9 to be bright red when D7 = 0 and D9 is empty.

Without seeing the actual sheet, it's hard to get more specific than that.

Comment: Hey Dick, thanks a million, I think I do need to go the calculate route but I have no idea what the Syntax is in my current script. And yes it may sound annoying to pop a message every time an update occurs, but updates my not occur but once a week.

Comment: See the edit for a calculate event example. Note there is no 'Target' as the whole sheet is calculated.

Comment: Yes Dick! This is it, deeply appreciated! Thanks all. Got it.